# Find the median line from the input broken line

Tags: postgis, line, median

[image: Find the median line from the input broken line]

I already tried to use `ST_Simplify`, but as the result `Wrong Line` was gotten, because the function reduced the number of points significantly and curvature was lost.

Is it possible to get the `Desired Line` while keeping maximum shape?

Example of data:

```
LINESTRING(-84.28218748821607 36.062298255863915,-84.28016833333335 36.06324,-84.27880833333332 36.06454166666666,-84.27893 36.06476833333333,-84.27872 36.064645000000006,-84.27883333333332 36.06478833333333,-84.278695 36.06469833333333,-84.27877333333332 36.064825000000006,-84.27838166666668 36.06502,-84.27849166666668 36.06512166666666,-84.27825166666668 36.06514166666667,-84.27825333333334 36.06540333333333,-84.27802833333332 36.06537333333333,-84.27746333333334 36.06598666666666,-84.27755333333334 36.06616,-84.27733000000002 36.06611833333333,-84.27603333333333 36.067495,-84.27615666666667 36.067618333333336,-84.27601666666666 36.06750666666667,-84.27550333333332 36.06791,-84.27550833333335 36.067775,-84.27350833333334 36.06926833333333,-84.27332499999999 36.06935166666666,-84.27321500000001 36.06911333333333,-84.27326166666666 36.06934833333333,-84.27319333333335 36.06917666666666,-84.27325 36.069345,-84.27318166666667 36.069185,-84.27323166666665 36.06935666666666,-84.27252166666668 36.06989333333333,-84.27162000000001 36.07021,-84.27155666666667 36.07054666666667,-84.27138166666667 36.07033833333333,-84.27020166666668 36.07092333333333,-84.26993666666667 36.07100666666667,-84.26991666666666 36.070863333333335,-84.269795 36.07106666666667,-84.26972666666667 36.070926666666665,-84.26942 36.07131,-84.26936499999998 36.07111333333333,-84.269075 36.07123166666667,-84.26888333333333 36.07168833333333,-84.26881999999999 36.071331666666666,-84.26854166666665 36.071668333333335,-84.26848999999999 36.071435,-84.26794 36.07182833333333,-84.26790833333334 36.071686666666665,-84.26755166666665 36.07184,-84.26770166666665 36.072091666666665,-84.26753333333333 36.071848333333335,-84.26718333333335 36.07227,-84.26692 36.07221666666667,-84.26699833333332 36.072363333333335,-84.26679333333335 36.072195,-84.26689833333333 36.07241,-84.26648833333333 36.07212666666667,-84.26671166666665 36.072455,-84.26652833333334 36.07269333333333,-84.26631833333334 36.07255833333333,-84.266325 36.072853333333335,-84.26438666666667 36.07391,-84.255975 36.075763333333335,-84.25457999999999 36.07587,-84.252335 36.07546333333333,-84.25030666666667 36.07452166666667,-84.25044166666666 36.07442,-84.24964666666668 36.07429666666667,-84.249725 36.07410333333333,-84.24952666666668 36.07419333333333,-84.24870666666666 36.07376,-84.24784 36.07313166666667,-84.24774833333335 36.07281666666667,-84.24759 36.072905,-84.24768999999999 36.07273333333333,-84.24753166666666 36.072835000000005,-84.24728833333332 36.07254666666667,-84.24679499999999 36.071555,-84.24689666666667 36.07124666666667,-84.24674666666667 36.07128,-84.24668666666666 36.07081166666667,-84.24715333333333 36.07058166666666,-84.24667166666669 36.070675,-84.24714 36.07045,-84.24667166666669 36.07066666666666,-84.24663833333334 36.07052,-84.24711833333335 36.07021333333333,-84.24662333333332 36.07024333333333,-84.247105 36.07006166666667,-84.24658333333333 36.07017166666667,-84.24701666666667 36.06991666666667,-84.24657499999999 36.06998166666666,-84.24651 36.06975333333333,-84.24673666666668 36.06971333333333,-84.24646333333334 36.06959333333334,-84.24668333333332 36.06948333333333,-84.24645666666666 36.069563333333335,-84.24616833333333 36.06881333333333,-84.24609000000001 36.068425000000005,-84.24636333333335 36.06827166666667,-84.24608666666667 36.06840166666667,-84.24635833333332 36.068216666666665,-84.24603166666665 36.068325,-84.24583066258008 36.06700621709043)
```

Comment: looks like you used too high a tolerance in your simplify command try a smaller number

Comment: I tried, but it is super hard to find an optimal tolerance value.

Comment: then reproject to a better projection and use a distance in metres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform to a projected coordinate system, simplify, buffer, smooth, find its medial axis.

```
with cte as (
select st_setsrid(
st_geomfromewkt('LINESTRING(-84.28218748821607 36.062298255863915,-84.28016833333335 36.06324,-84.27880833333332 36.06454166666666,-84.27893 36.06476833333333,-84.27872 36.064645000000006,-84.27883333333332 36.06478833333333,-84.278695 36.06469833333333,-84.27877333333332 36.064825000000006,-84.27838166666668 36.06502,-84.27849166666668 36.06512166666666,-84.27825166666668 36.06514166666667,-84.27825333333334 36.06540333333333,-84.27802833333332 36.06537333333333,-84.27746333333334 36.06598666666666,-84.27755333333334 36.06616,-84.27733000000002 36.06611833333333,-84.27603333333333 36.067495,-84.27615666666667 36.067618333333336,-84.27601666666666 36.06750666666667,-84.27550333333332 36.06791,-84.27550833333335 36.067775,-84.27350833333334 36.06926833333333,-84.27332499999999 36.06935166666666,-84.27321500000001 36.06911333333333,-84.27326166666666 36.06934833333333,-84.27319333333335 36.06917666666666,-84.27325 36.069345,-84.27318166666667 36.069185,-84.27323166666665 36.06935666666666,-84.27252166666668 36.06989333333333,-84.27162000000001 36.07021,-84.27155666666667 36.07054666666667,-84.27138166666667 36.07033833333333,-84.27020166666668 36.07092333333333,-84.26993666666667 36.07100666666667,-84.26991666666666 36.070863333333335,-84.269795 36.07106666666667,-84.26972666666667 36.070926666666665,-84.26942 36.07131,-84.26936499999998 36.07111333333333,-84.269075 36.07123166666667,-84.26888333333333 36.07168833333333,-84.26881999999999 36.071331666666666,-84.26854166666665 36.071668333333335,-84.26848999999999 36.071435,-84.26794 36.07182833333333,-84.26790833333334 36.071686666666665,-84.26755166666665 36.07184,-84.26770166666665 36.072091666666665,-84.26753333333333 36.071848333333335,-84.26718333333335 36.07227,-84.26692 36.07221666666667,-84.26699833333332 36.072363333333335,-84.26679333333335 36.072195,-84.26689833333333 36.07241,-84.26648833333333 36.07212666666667,-84.26671166666665 36.072455,-84.26652833333334 36.07269333333333,-84.26631833333334 36.07255833333333,-84.266325 36.072853333333335,-84.26438666666667 36.07391,-84.255975 36.075763333333335,-84.25457999999999 36.07587,-84.252335 36.07546333333333,-84.25030666666667 36.07452166666667,-84.25044166666666 36.07442,-84.24964666666668 36.07429666666667,-84.249725 36.07410333333333,-84.24952666666668 36.07419333333333,-84.24870666666666 36.07376,-84.24784 36.07313166666667,-84.24774833333335 36.07281666666667,-84.24759 36.072905,-84.24768999999999 36.07273333333333,-84.24753166666666 36.072835000000005,-84.24728833333332 36.07254666666667,-84.24679499999999 36.071555,-84.24689666666667 36.07124666666667,-84.24674666666667 36.07128,-84.24668666666666 36.07081166666667,-84.24715333333333 36.07058166666666,-84.24667166666669 36.070675,-84.24714 36.07045,-84.24667166666669 36.07066666666666,-84.24663833333334 36.07052,-84.24711833333335 36.07021333333333,-84.24662333333332 36.07024333333333,-84.247105 36.07006166666667,-84.24658333333333 36.07017166666667,-84.24701666666667 36.06991666666667,-84.24657499999999 36.06998166666666,-84.24651 36.06975333333333,-84.24673666666668 36.06971333333333,-84.24646333333334 36.06959333333334,-84.24668333333332 36.06948333333333,-84.24645666666666 36.069563333333335,-84.24616833333333 36.06881333333333,-84.24609000000001 36.068425000000005,-84.24636333333335 36.06827166666667,-84.24608666666667 36.06840166666667,-84.24635833333332 36.068216666666665,-84.24603166666665 36.068325,-84.24583066258008 36.06700621709043)'),
4326) as geom)

select ST_ChaikinSmoothing(
(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(
st_simplify(st_buffer(
st_transform(geom, 32616)
, 20)
, 30)
)), 5) as geometry

from cte
```

[image]